# What is the use of parenthesis used for in JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, html

What are things inside the parenthesis used for?

Like, what is the use of getCookies**(name)** and in the latter part, another word is used in place for it, like getCookies**("counter")**

```js
function getCookies(name)
  var dc = document.cookie;
  var prefix = name + "=";
  var begin = dc.indexOf("; " + prefix);
  if (begin == -1) {
    begin = dc.indexOf(prefix);
    if (begin != 0) return null;
  } else
    begin += 2;
  var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
  if (end == -1)
    end = dc.length;
  return unescape(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
}
```

The latter script:

```js
<!--
var now = new Date();
fixDate(now);


now.setTime(now.getTime() + 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
var visits = getCookie("counter");
if (!visits) {
} else {
  visits = parseInt(visits) + 1;
}
  document.write("You have been here " + visits + " time(s).");

setCookie("counter", visits, now);
// -->
```

Thank you

Comment: The first one is a parameter name, and the second one is the value passed for that parameter when the function is called. That’s such an absolute basic concept … I wouldn’t even know how to explain it any further.

Comment: These are arguments passed to a function.  This is the very, very basics of almost any programming language.  I'd suggest you find a good tutorial site or book on Javascript and start there.

Comment: Are you talking about function [arguments](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp)? If you're wondering about the downvotes, this really is a basic concept...

Comment: Guys cmon with the downvotes. It's a basic question but that doesn't mean it can't be answered. Everyone has to start somewhere and I think it's better to help them than criticize.

Comment: Parameters vs. Arguments

Comment: Thank you everyone for their criticism and helpful comments. I am not new to programming, but to JavaScript. I was really confused between parameter (couldn't figure out the name, that was the really problem...) and arrays, which is one of the things that made programming like hell (the arrays) for me to understand... Thank you :)

Comment: There is also the (somewhat incomplete) MDN article on the [*grouping operator*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript there are things called `functions` that help you organize and reuse your code. The structure for one looks like this

```
function (parameter1, parameter2) {
   //Some code
}
```

A parameter is a value that you can pass to the function. So for instance, you might have a function like this:

```
function add(num1, num2) {
   return num1 + num2;
}
```

That function can then be run and assigned to a variable like this:

```
answer1 = add(1,2) //answer1 = 3
answer2 = add(5,7) //answer2 = 12
...
```

These are pretty basic programming fundamentals, however. I would recommend doing some JavaScript tutorials.  [Code Academy](https://www.codecademy.com/) has a good one.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, just couldn't figure out the name of it and confused it with arrays. I just have one more follow up question, suppose you give a parameter the word "name" and use "name" inside the function declaration, would this be replaced with the information entered in the place of "name" (meaning that are they both the same)?

Comment: If you have code that looks like this `var foo = 'bar'; function test (foo) { alert(foo); }` and run `test('baz')` it'll alert `baz` not `bar`. Does that clarify?

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

This declares a function named `f` which receives one parameter named `arg`:

```js
function f(arg) {
  // Code here...
}
```

Then, when you want to execute the code of the function `f`, you may want to pass some information to it. So you pass some argument:

```
f("foo");
f(123);
f(null);
```

If you use the variable `arg` inside the code of the function, the value of that variable will be the argument passed as the parameter in that call.

For example:

```
function f(arg) {
  alert(arg * 2);
}
f(1); // Alerts 2
f(2); // Alerts 4
```

Comment: Arguments are actually only in your second code block. The first code block demonstrates a parameter. Subtlety, but important.

Comment: @J4G I think you are being a bit nitpicky, but OK, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a function you also declare its arguments inside the brackets ().

When you call the function you pass to the function a value for each argument.

I know this is a rough description of the item but consider it a starting point to learn some JavaScript. Variable defined outside of a function must be referenced (this way) inside the function to be used for elaborating.

Still... This is not exhaustive but starting from this I think you can learn by yourself googling a bit